# getting img src from json data while using AngularJS ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

So I got a interesting question to which I haven't found a answer to.

Let's say I got a bunch of data coming from a JSON file like, but somehow one of the main fields looks like this

```
description : '<img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/37c38989a5f26031be3e0ec5ffc5cd2/200012386/got-hbo-go-crash-2014-04-07-01_thumbnail.jpg"/> Viewing of the Game of Thrones season debut came to a crashing halt yesterday thanks to server problems with HBO Go. The cable outfit first reported the problem late yesterday via Twitter, and finally restored full service early this morning. That...'
```

How would I be able to get the src from that IMG while using ng-bind-html to bind the json data to the innerHTML on my page. ( using display:none; on the img itself so it would'nt display )

I have tried getElementsByTags and so on, but nothing returned a valid value.

Is there some kind of "angular" way to do it or... ?

BR's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the html stored in the object you could do this:

```
var json = {description : '<img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/37c38989a5f26031be3e0ec5ffc5cd2/200012386/got-hbo-go-crash-2014-04-07-01_thumbnail.jpg"/> Viewing of the Game of Thrones season debut came to a crashing halt yesterday thanks to server problems with HBO Go. The cable outfit first reported the problem late yesterday via Twitter, and finally restored full service early this morning. That...'};

  $scope.imgPath = '';

  $scope.getImage = function() {
    el = angular.element(angular.element('<div>' + json.description + '</div>').find('img')[0]);
    $scope.imgPath = el.attr('src');

  }
```

Here is a demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/JXy97lrN5FyW1MK33qO1?p=preview

This solution assumes jQuery isn't included in the project.

This also works:

```
 $scope.imgPath = angular.element(json.description).attr('src');
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/zVllp9bmsU2DoZwDZnCY?p=info

Answer (score 2):

The angular way of doing this would be to write a filter that does the massaging that you need.

Something like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="data | extractSrcUrl"></div>
```

and then

```
app.filter('extractSrcUrl', function () {
  return function (text) {
      var output = awesomeRegexExtractionStuff(text); // fill this in
      return output;
  }
});
```

I attempted a jsfiddle but I couldn't quite get the regex right. [Here it is anyway](http://jsfiddle.net/LxK7W/1/).

Edit: I updated my fiddle using @lucuma's way of extracting the url: http://jsfiddle.net/LxK7W/2/

Comment: that's pretty good but let's say it has more then 1 image within the description. It Doesn't return anything then. Why is that. Shouldn't it return at least one value ?

Comment: It seemed to still return one when I played around with it. Can you post the html that failed? Also I made another jsfiddle that gets all the image sources. Right now it just concatenates them but it might be a useful start. http://jsfiddle.net/LxK7W/3/