# AngularJS regex json data for img src or other selectors

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm new to angular, so bear with me here.... I've a simple, but dirty, json results file I am pulling into my angularjs page. I am trying to get just the img src from the first img that is found in the returned info. Here is a fiddle with it setup:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = "HEREHLKSDJFKLFJSLK:FJKFJ:KLJSL:KDfj<img src=\"http://www.sierraavalanchecenter.org/sites/default/files/forecast/201411/20141113-074138-0.png\"/ >asdfsdjflksdfj;kasdfkjs;dklfs;df";
});

app.filter('extractSrcUrl', function () {
    return function (text) {
        var output = angular.element(text).attr('src');
        return(output);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9jst560/

If found the filter idea via this post: [getting img src from json data while using AngularJS ng-bind-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037549/getting-img-src-from-json-data-while-using-angularjs-ng-bind-html)

If I get rid of all the json data and just leave: http://www.sierraavalanchecenter.org/sites/default/files/forecast/201411/20141113-074138-0.png\"/ > the filter pulls out the src fine.

However, with my messy data, no results. Should I be using regex somewhere in my controller rather than running filter? Is my data that bad?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/j9jst560/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either of the following.

Modify your selector code to the following:

```
var output = angular.element('<div>' + text + '</div>').find('img')[0].attr('src')
```

Which is probably the safest and easiest way. Note that in angular 1.2 and below (I believe they fixed it in 1.3) this has to be as follows:

```
var output = angular.element(angular.element('<div>' + text + '</div>').find('img')[0]).attr('src')
```

The other way is to extract purely using regex as follows:

```
var output = text.match(/src="([^"]*)"/i)[1]
```

As a side note - `return` isn't a function, normally it's just called as `return output;`.